# Can't figure out what is wrong with this Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, pdo, warnings, standards

I get an error on the line where I bind values in the following function:

```
    function update_vote_logs($accid, $site_id){
    global $host_ip, $auth_db, $db_username, $db_password, $character_db, $world_db, $web_db;
    $con = connect($host_ip, $db_username, $db_password, $web_db);
    $exp = time() + (43200);
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO `vote_logs` VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    if (check_if_voted($accid, $site_id) == 0 || check_if_voted($accid, $site_id) == 2){
        if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $accid, $site_id, time(), $exp);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
}
```

This is the line which causes the error:

```
 $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $accid, $site_id, time(), $exp);
```

I'm learning PHP and this is the first time I've seen this warning.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have a feeling that time() is causing the issue because it is not a variable but as I'm not 100% sure

Comment: You are right. `$now=time(); ...bind_param("iiii", $accid, $site_id, $now, $exp);`

Comment: yes that was it :D  thank you :)

Comment: Instead of `bind_param` there is also a `bind_value` will would work here because you are not using the bind within a loop which is where you would want to bind by reference to a variable.

Comment: There is no bind_value for mysqli. @Jonathan Kuhn

Comment: @VolkerK Thank you, I stand corrected. I'm just used to PDO and didn't notice the format as mysqli. For this to work here, you would have to store the result of `time()` in a variable and use that with your bind. Also, @OP, don't disconnect and reconnect for every query. Connect once and use that connection for all your queries. Connecting and disconnecting take time. You are essentially re-doing the same thing over and over for each query. You could change your `connect` function to have a static variable and return that if it is valid else connect. Then just remove the close.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $accid, $site_id, time(), $exp); is wrong. You need to use bindParam for one, and you need to use it for EACH variable. Else you need to use an array